# error importing multiple files at same time

Tags: matlab

Trying to join different files with an specific suffix in a matrix, but always I obtain a matrix with unique row containing the values of the last file..

As example

I have multiple files like:

```
2302_Cabeza_L_x.txt, 2202_Cabeza_L_x.txt, 1702_Cabeza_L_y.txt.....
```

The code I'm using...

```
codes= [2302,2202,1602,1502,1702];

for p=1:length(codes)

name=mat2str(codes(:,p));

    orden2=(name(2:length(name)-11));
    orden=str2num(orden2);

allCABLX = importdata([name '_Cabeza_L_x.txt']);
allCABLY = importdata([name '_Cabeza_L_y.txt']);
allCABCY = importdata([name '_Cabeza_C_y.txt']);
allCABCX = importdata([name '_Cabeza_C_x.txt']);
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the variables `allCABLX`, `allCABLY`, `allCABCY` and `allCABCX` in every iteration, so only the last values stay there after the loop. You need to save the data inside the loop to be able to access it afterwards.

If all files have the same number of entries, this can be achieved by concatenating the values obtained by `importdata`. Since I don't know the dimensions of the output of `importdata`, I'm not going into the details here.

If the files have different number of entries, you can use a cell array to store the data of each iteration. This works as well in case all entries are of the same size. The following code does exactly this for one of the variables:

```
codes= [2302,2202,1602,1502,1702];

allCABLX = cell(length(codes),1);   % create empty cell array
for p=1:length(codes)
    name=num2str(codes(:,p));
    allCABLX{p} = importdata([name '_Cabeza_L_x.txt']);
end
```

Note that I replaced `mat2str` by `num2str` since you only have a number to convert and not a whole matrix. In case all the files have data of the same dimension, you can use `cell2mat` after the loop to get a *normal* matrix.